# How do I read a JWT Token in a Cookie and leave a logged in user? I am working on MERN stack App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

This is my API.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

This is my Axios call to backend for login:

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/loginUser',
  async (email, password) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    const { data } = await API.post(
      'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login',
      { email, password },
      config
    );

    return data;
  }
);
```

This is my state, dispatch and submit form handler:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const user = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { pending, error, userInfo } = user;

  console.log(userInfo);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginUser(email, password));
  };
```

Everything works great, I can log in and my JWT token is placed in my Cookie, but when I refresh the page I lose all user data (as if it is not logged in) and I still have JWT in my Cookie. How do I keep a logged in user while his token or cookie is still active?

Comment: How is your server code using the cookie?

Comment: @Joe

const signToken = id => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, 'my-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret', {
    expiresIn: '14d',
  });
};

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);

  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 14 * 1000 * 60 * 24),
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  // Remove password from output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user,
    },
  });
};

Answer (score 0):

You can create an API route to check if the user is logged in e.g `http://localhost/api/auth/me` which verifies if **Cookie** is valid then return
a response with the user like `res.json({success:true,user:verifiedUser})`
and on the frontend use can use **UseEffect** hook to check for the user on every page refresh like `useEffect(()=>{ CheckUser() },[])`

CheckUser could be any function of your choice.